# Directory completion in Perl Getopt::Complete callback

Tags: perl, tabs, completion

In a Perl script, I use [`Getopt::Complete`](http://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Complete) for automatic completion using the tab key. Everything works well, except for one feature I would like to implement.

I'd like to use a callback that, under some circumstances, provides 'directory' completion. However, returning 'directory' from the callback does not work, as an array reference is expected.

```
use Getopt::Complete (
    '<>' => sub {
        my ( $command, $value, $option, $other_opts ) = @_;
        if ( $other_opts->{'<>'} ) {
            return 'directories';    ## here I'd like directory completion
        }
        return ['foo'];
    }
);
```

How can this behaviour be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not tested!**

After looking at the documentation I believe you can just treat the `'directories'` as an actual sub. It's being generated in [Getopt::Complete::Compgen](https://metacpan.org/source/NNUTTER/Getopt-Complete-0.26/lib/Getopt/Complete/Compgen.pm) and ends up as `Getopt::Complete::directories`. So you should be able to simply call that.

```
use Getopt::Complete (
    '<>' => sub {
        my ( $command, $value, $option, $other_opts ) = @_;
        if ( $other_opts->{'<>'} ) {
            return Getopt::Complete::directories(
                $command, 
                $value, 
                $option, 
                $other_opts,
            ); # forward to directory
        }
        return ['foo'];
    }
);
```

Comment: Perfect! This works. I had tried calling 'directories' but not passed down @_